# Yeast for my first homebrew

Tags: yeast

I live in a country where its difficult to get yeast for home brewing, so can someone guide me to a way to ferment?
I heard that if you make grape juice and leave it in the open for few days it will have yeast in it? have anyone try that or should i just go with bread yeast?
I couldn't find hops neither but i'm going to try with black tea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving grape juice open to the air will usually inoculate it naturally with wild yeasts, but this is a hit-or-miss sort of thing. You may have a beneficial fermentation, or a bad one. Worse, you have a high risk of bacterial infections or mold.

Bread yeast (S. Cerevisiae) is not well suited for wine fermentations; it struggles with the pH of the must (wine yeast is more acid resistant) and its alcohol tolerance tends to be too low. Some bread yeasts can handle up to 10% or so, but this is by no means guaranteed; it may max out at 5% or even less.

Still, beers can be brewed using bread yeast. Whether or not that will produce the right flavour depends on the strain of yeast and is impossible to predict, so experiment!

As already noted above, hops act as a preservative. Black tea doesn't have that property (to speak of). However if you brew very cleanly and do not expect your beer to have a decent shelf life, this is not necessarily the end of brewing. The other function of hops is to provide bitterness in order to balance out the malty sweetness of the beer. Before hops were used a wide variety of bitter herbs were staples of brewing. Google for "gruit" and see what you can find locally.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Bread yeast are normally cultured to stop fermenting at far below 5 %, not enough to get beer or wine dry.

I would rather add a single raisin or culture a strong starter, starting with a minced raisin in a slightly acidic environment - such as 25 mL water and 25 mL fresh pineapple juice.  I will then feed using 50 mL starter and 50 mL wort/juice until it becomes active enough.

Look at how they do bread starter and use the same method to make a fermentation starter.

Hops is a crucial ingredient for beer - as taste and preservative.  Order some by mail or find a source in your country.  I am sure it is widely planted.